# How can I get multiple lists as separate results from a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Suppose I have this code:

```
def f(x):
    return 2*x,x*x

x = range(3)
xlist, ylist = [f(value) for value in x]
```

How can I neatly get a result like this?

```
xlist = [0, 2, 4]
ylist = [0, 1, 4]
```

Comment: A list comprehension should not be used to make two lists. You can, of course, use `zip` to transpose your list of tuples into two lists, but why try to shoe-horn a list comprehension here? Just iterate through your tuples and append to two lists... keep it simple.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I don't know if I agree with that: first of all list comprehension works faster than appending (on one list, indeed when feeding two lists it can be less efficient). Furthermore it is declarative style to use not that much operations with side effects: list comprehension has usually no side effects: one usually writes code that is convenient for *readers*, not *writers*. Furthermore why is this question downvoted?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I didn't downvote it, for the record. But, using a comprehension, *and then* zipping it, will likely *not* be faster, unless you use a generator comprehension so you do it in one pass instead of building the list of tuples into memory first. But then, likely, wrapping a for-loop in a function will likely give you as good or better performance than using the generator (which decreases performance). Also, it's a matter of style and readability but I guess that is subjective.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I agree with willem Van Onsem.  The intention here is that the code should have a very clear meaning for later readers.  The efficiency is a bonus but I feel that the line: 
xlist, ylist = zip(*[f(value) for value in x])
has a clear functionality, and is more interpretable than a for loop splitting a list.

Comment: You really think it is more clear than `for value in x: a,b = f(value); list1.append(a); list2.append(b)`?

Comment: Anyway, my point here is that you will always have to make superfluous intermediate data-structures, especially if you use a list comprehension, but even if you replaced your list comprehension with a generator expression: `zip(*(f(x) for x in values))` because argument unpacking exhausts the iterator... That sort of thing just bugs me, and likely if this isn't a bottleneck it's fine. Perhaps I'm just being too obsessive. But just note that you can do it in one pass with a for-loop, but these other methods involve multiple passes.

Comment: I think it depends whether you are trying to debug or understand the intended function.  Perhaps harder to debug but I think that the intended function is more clear, yes.  In addition I'm using this function to generate information for figures, so while 4 lines is not significantly worse than 1 line; if it is replicated 4 times (for each subfigure) it uses quite a bit of unnecessary space.

Comment: @Christophe well, that's *what functions are for*.

Comment: A function would also take one line to call, per subfigure.  And I could move the subfigure generating code into a function but as a style choice I'd rather have one less layer of complexity and a few lines repeated (as long as there aren't too many)

Comment: Please do not edit answers into the question. This is **not a discussion forum**. I rolled back the change.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Note that `return 2*x,x` is short for `return (2*x,x)`, i.e. **a tuple**. Your list comprehension thus **generates a list of tuples**, not a tuple of lists. The nice thing of `zip` however **is that you can easily use it in reverse** with the asterisk:

```
xlist,ylist = zip(*[f(value) for value in x])
#                 ^ with asterisk
```

Note that `xlist` and `ylist` will be **tuples** (since `zip` will be unpacked). If you want them to be lists, you can for instance use:

```
xlist,ylist = map(list, zip(*[f(value) for value in x]))
```

which results in:

```
>>> xlist
[0, 2, 4]
>>> ylist
[0, 1, 4]
```

Another way to do this is with separate list comprehensions:

```
xlist = [f(value)[0] for value in x]
ylist = [f(value)[1] for value in x]
```

Of course, this repeats the work of `f`, which is inelegant and can be inefficient.

Comment: good call on the edit, I was generating a simple version and didn't test the simple version, I'll update the prompt.

Comment: Good catch on he mapping too.  In my case I'm iterating over the return so lists or tuples are both fine but that is good to note.

Answer (score 7):

Let's make this work. The function is fine:

```
def f(x):
  return 2*x, x*x
```

But you want to define the range as follows, notice the starting and ending values:

```
x = range(1, 4)
```

Also, you have to call the function with the *value*, not with the *list* as parameter. And the final trick to unzip the result into two lists, is to simply `zip(*lst)` the result of the list comprehension:

```
xlist, ylist = zip(*[f(value) for value in x])
```

Now the result is as expected:

```
xlist 
=> [2, 4, 6]
ylist 
=> [1, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the build-in function [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip),

```
def f(x):
  return 2*x, x*x

x = range(1, 4)
xlist, ylist = zip(*[f(value) for value in x])

print(xlist, ylist)
# ((2, 4, 6), (1, 4, 9))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
zip(*your_list_of_bituples)
```

Example

```
demo_list = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
zip(*demo_list)
```

Will give

```
[(1, 2, 4), (2, 3, 5)]
```

Comment: I didn't even consider zip(*) but that is absolutely the right tool, and it solved my problem.  Thank you for the quick reply (I'll accept in a few minutes once it is allowed).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but the following gets what you want.

```
def f(value):
    xlist = []
    ylist = []
    for x, y in [(2*x, x*x) for x in range(value)]:
        xlist.append(x)
        ylist.append(y)
    return xlist, ylist

x = int(input("enter a value: "))
xval, yval = f(x)

print(f"xlist = {xval}\nylist = {yval}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x):
    yield [2*x, x*x]
        
xlist, ylist = zip(*[next(f(x)) for x in range(3)])

print(list(xlist))
print(list(ylist))
```

using yield...

```
[0, 2, 4]
[0, 1, 4]

[Program finished]
```